# convert html to pdf which has multiple canvas and table

Tags: jquery, css, html5-canvas, jspdf, flotr2

I am converting html page which has multiple canvas and has some text into single pdf as it is created from flotr.js(it has lot of charts created using flotr.js). How to combine these all charts and text into single pdf file. I tried a lot with jspdf but i didn't get any answer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in tow step :
 - Convert your html page on image drawing in a canvas.
 - Generate a PDF from your canvas.
Just follow this tutorial : http://www.techumber.com/html-to-pdf-conversion-using-javascript/

Get html2canvas.js and jspdf.js